# undocumented unequality operator <> in lua?

Tags: lua

While reading through the pages of *Programming in Lua*, I experimented in a Lua 5.3 console. In [3.3 – Logical Operators](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html), I read (and tried out) that `not 0` evaluates to `false` - quite shocking for me as a C/C++ programmer. For practice I wrote a function that checks if a given number is different from `0`:

```lua
Lua> function nn(x) return x <> 0 end
```

Despite the bogus operator,<sup>[1]</sup> the function did exactly what it was supposed to:

```lua
Lua> nn(1)
true
Lua> nn(0)
false
Lua> nn(0.0)
false
Lua> nn(0.5)
true
Lua> nn(-1)
true
```

When I realized that the actual [inequality operator being `~=`](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.2.html), I wondered why I didn't get an error message. So I assumed that version 5.3 (that I'm experimenting with) could have introduced an alias for `~=`, but I see that this is not the case in the [Lua 5.3 reference, 3.4.4 – Relational Operators](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.4).

Can someone shed some light on what's really happening here?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> 
I obviously had the unmistakable feeling that the operator `<>` known from SQL, Basic or Pascal would be perfect for Lua ;)

Comment: better stick to the reference manual than to your unmistakable feelings ;)

Comment: Can you use `!` instead of `not` in the console?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff No: "stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '!'"

Comment: Can you use [C-style comments](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Specific_Operators) in Lua?

Comment: Please upload (pastebin.com) the list of available globals in your console: `for g in pairs(_G) do print(g) end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff here it is: https://pastebin.com/c6NPeBnU

Comment: Luas syntax is largely based on Pascal, so it seems reasonable that it would use `<>`, but at the same time, `<>` as "not equal" only makes sense for numbers, were "unequal" and "larger or smaller" are equivalent; when you're dealing with types like strings though, that equivalence breaks and `<>` stops being a reasonable operator. Lua being a scripting language with more emphasis on structured data than on numbers, it makes sense to use `~=` instead

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff C-style comments (`/* like this */`) are not allowed, I also tested `// the line comments of C++`

Comment: The only difference in the globals I detected (comparing with freshly downloaded 5.3.4 and 5.3.5 versions) is the absence of `bit32` in my questionable 5.3.4 console.

Comment: `bit32` is included only when Lua is built with 5.2 compatibility flag

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - Why `<>` is not a reasonable operator for strings?

Comment: @Wolf - Please post an example of bytecode: `print(table.concat({string.dump(function()end):byte(1,-1)},','))`

Comment: you probably meant this: `Lua>print(table.concat({string.dump(function(x)return x<>0 end):byte(1,-1)},','))
27,76,117,97,83,0,25,147,13,10,26,10,4,4,4,8,8,120,86,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,40,119,64,0,7,61,115,116,100,105,110,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,2,6,0,0,0,
31,0,64,0,30,0,0,128,67,64,0,0,67,0,128,0,102,0,0,1,38,0,128,0,1,0,0,0,
19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,
0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,120,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

Comment: Interestingly the same as `Lua>print(table.concat({string.dump(function(x)return x~=0 end):byte(1,-1)},','))
27,76,117,97,83,0,25,147,13,10,26,10,4,4,4,8,8,120,86,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,40,119,64,0,7,61,115,116,100,105,110,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,2,6,0,0,0,
31,0,64,0,30,0,0,128,67,64,0,0,67,0,128,0,102,0,0,1,38,0,128,0,1,0,0,0,
19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,
0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,120,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

Comment: The bytecode is identical to usual Lua 5.3 bytecode on 32-bit x86 system

Comment: So the interpreter seems to have `<>` as an alias to `~=` hard coded in its lexer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in my Lua 5.3 console. When I try the same

```lua
function nn(x) return x <> 0 end

nn(0)
nn(0.1)
nn(0.0)
nn(10)
nn(-10)
```

in [ideone](https://ideone.com/rGXOfa) (running *Lua (luac 5.3.3)*), I get this syntax error:

> luac5.3: prog.lua:1: unexpected symbol near '>'

The same as I get in the [Lua live demo](https://www.lua.org/demo.html) (*Lua 5.3.5 Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio*)

> input:1: unexpected symbol near '>'

Comment: and what Lua 5.3 console might that be? I tried 3 and none of them ignored your syntax error.

Comment: really interesting, I tried 2 (5.3.5 and 5.3.4, 32-bit windows tools packages from SF) and both reject `<>` as syntax error. I have to figure out, where I have this console from (it says that it's version 5.3.4 "lua53 -v" gave
"Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio")

Comment: BTW: It's this mystical console is a standalone exe that is exactly 65,536 Bytes in size, I now remember that I didn't compile it myself...

Comment: Lua executable doesn't fit in 64K.  Probably, there is a DLL nearby?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff There is no DLL nearby and also not in the path. I tried the other ones (around 40K each) which failed in both cases because of the missing DLL.

Comment: Usual 32-bit lua53.dll is about 160 KBytes

Comment: Well, I have to correct the sizes I gave. For Lua 5.3.5 it is lua53.dll:385KB, lua53.exe:135KB. Fur Lua 5.3.4 it is lua53.dll:297KB, lua53.exe:106KB. Nevertheless the interpreter in question is 64KB and doesn't import any functions besides `LoadLibraryA`, `ExitProcess`, `GetProcAddress`, `VirtualProtect` from `KERNEL32.DLL` and `abs` from `msvcrt.dll`

Comment: I uploaded the [hexdump of this lua53.exe](https://pastebin.com/x2k0pjij)

Comment: @Wolf - This EXE is packed with UPX, hence the size

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I see, thanks you share your knowledge. I already observed this for EXEs unusual distribution of bytes, now I know that this is how [UPX](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPX)-packed EXEs look like.

Comment: It's 230K when unpacked.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Does it (the unpacked binary) tell something about it's source?

Comment: IDK. To unpack, use, for example [UPX 3.08](https://mega.nz/folder/OAx0wL7K#gLPZh7pkMv7d8as5serOmg)

Comment: This is one of the “problems” of Lua.  Because the language is so small, simple, and hackable you find a lot of customized versions floating around on the internet.